# How do you know if a complex function is injective or surjective

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

so I was given the following equation:

$f : \Bbb{C} \to\Bbb{C}$

$f(x+iy) = (3x + 2) + i(y^2 - 1)$

and was asked if it was injective, then if it was surjective, and then what the range of this function is.  I am not sure how to answer this as you cant really graph functions on the complex plane as it is too hard to visualise! any sort of help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Try solving (3x+2) + i(y^2-1) = a+ib, given that x, y, a, and b are all real. For what values of a and b are both of the real equations solvable?

Comment: In this example, just look at the imaginary part to find the answer to both injectivity and surjectivity

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is injective:  If $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$, it must be that $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$.

So, suppose \begin{align*}
f(x_1, y_1) &= (3x_1+2)+\mathrm{i}(y_1^2−1)  \\
    &= (3x_2+2)+\mathrm{i}(y_2^2−1)  \\
    &= f(x_2,y_2)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \Bbb{R}$, $3x_1 + 2$ and $3x_2+2$ are the real parts of these two quantities, so $3x_1 + 2 = 3x_2+2$ and we deduce $x_1 = x_2$.  Similarly, \begin{align*}
y_1^2 - 1 &= y_2^2 -1  \\
y_1^2 &= y_2^2  \\
y_1^2 = y_2^2 &= 0  \\
(y_1 + y_2)(y_1 - y_2) &= 0  \text{,}
\end{align*}
from which we deduce $y_1 = y_2$ or $y_1 = -y_2$.  But this means $f$ (generically) takes two points to the same image, so is not injective.

You should recognize that the imaginary part of $f$ is lower bounded, so immediately be able to respond to surjectivity.

For the range, we want to know what values of $a + \mathrm{i}b$ are output by $f$.  So set $f(x,y) = a + \mathrm{i}b$, (split into real and imaginary parts,) and solve for $x$ and $y$.  You will find that you can get any $a$ you want by choosing the appropriate $x$.  However, $b$ is lower bounded (as observed earlier), so only the half of the Argand plane on or above a particular horizontal line is in the image.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to check injectivity, you have to consider the equation $f(z) = w$. $f$ is injective if this equation has *at most* one solution for every $w$. Now, for your function, it is easy to see that this is not the case since you have a quadratic in $y$ in the imaginary part. You see that

$$f(i)=2+ i (i^2-1) = 2-2i \quad \text{and} \quad f(-i) = 2+i((-i)^2-1) = 2-2i.$$

To check surjectivity, you consider the same equation. The function is surjective if $f(z) = w$ has *at least* one solution for every $w$. Hence, $f$ is bijective (surjective and injective) if the equation has *exactly* one solution for every $w$. Once again, we suspect that $f$ is not surjective since there is a quadratic in $y$ in the imaginary part. Consider for example the equation

$$f(z) = 2 - 3i.$$

We see that $\Re(z) = 0$ and $\Im(z)$ must satisfy $\Im(z)^2 -1 = -3 \implies \Im(z)^2 = -2,$ which is impossible.

In conclusion, $f$ is neither injective nor surjective. To find its image, consider the real and imaginary parts separately. $\Re(f)$ is a linear polynomial. Hence, the values of $f$ obtain all possible real parts. However, $\Im(f)$ is the quadratic $y^2-1$, whose image (seen as a map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) is $[-1, \infty)$. Hence, the image if $f$ is

$$f(\mathbb{C}) = \{ x + iy \in \mathbb{C} \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } y \in [-1, \infty) \}$$